# Minimum spanning tree classification problem with adjacent neighbors

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree

I am new to minimum spanning trees. But have used the last few days on a problem I think matches MST, but cannot really figure out the connection.

The problem is a minimum cost problem where N ordered sections 1...N all need to be connected. I.e. section N_k needs to be connected to it's adjacent neighbors N_k-1 and N_k+1. The cost function of connecting it to each of the neighbors depends on the value of N_k-1 and also whether or not N_k-1 is already connected to N_k-2 and in that case also the value of N_k-2...

Can anyone direct me to a programming example of a similar problem?

Comment: **Please add a reference to the original problem.** Why is this important? Reasons 1) Credit should be attributed. 2) The original problem is probably stated clearer, especially when the current question is not clear. 3) A reference will motivate people easily. 4) A reference may save readers who look for related materials lots of time.

Comment: I suspect this problem comes from an ongoing exam or contest because of the way the problem is stated and the lack of update from the asker. I cannot prove beyond reasonable doubt, of course. I will predict: 1) No more reference will be added in the near future. 2) the asker will not be active again. (Of course, I love to see that I will be proven wrong.)